# Quick Sort Implementation with iterators

Tags: c++, sorting, quick-sort

Most quicksort examples online use C-style arrays and indexes. I have written below quicksort implementation with STL style iterators. It looks fine to me, but I feel like I may be making more than necessary copies of iterators. I am open for any suggestions/improvements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter>
inline Iter partition(const Iter& beg, const Iter& end) {
  using std::swap;
  assert(beg != end);
  auto piv = end;
  --piv; // Pivot is the last element
  auto index_small = beg;

  for (auto index_large = beg; index_large != piv; ++index_large) {
    if (*index_large <= *piv) {
      swap(*index_large, *index_small);
      ++index_small;
    }
  }
  swap(*index_small, *piv);
  return index_small;
}

template <typename Iter>
void quick_sort(const Iter& beg, const Iter& end) {
  if (end - beg > 1) {
    const auto& piv = partition(beg, end);
    quick_sort(beg, piv);
    quick_sort(piv, end);
  }
}

// Test
int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{ 19, 54, 53, 9, 3, 96, 40, 36, 96, 43, 45,
                        78, 57, 6, 12, 100, 36, 15, 27, 45, 80, 39,
                        10, 71, 100, 15, 41, 43, 20, 32, 61, 2, 55,
                        33, 85, 32, 11, 50, 25, 17, 75, 74, 39, 49,
                        50, 17, 18, 55, 63, 81, };
  quick_sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have done a great job.  Here’s my suggestions:

- Sort the include directives in alphabetical order.
- Instead of using the generic name `Iter`, it may be a good idea to express the random access requirement: something like `RandomIt`.
- Iterators should be passed by value, not const reference.  Don’t be afraid to copy iterators — they are intended to be lightweight objects that are frequently copied, and passing them by const reference will incur overhead over passing them by value because of the additional indirection.
- It is more logical to use `auto piv = std::prev(end);`, because `int y = x - 1;` is more logical then `int y = x; --y;`, right?  (Of course you can use `end - 1`, but that may be less efficient if the subtraction operator of the iterator isn’t inlined.)
- You can use `std::iter_swap` instead of manually ADL’ing `swap`.
- Instead of enforcing `<=`, consider taking a custom comparator as the standard algorithms do.  (Also note that the standard library facilities always use `<` as the comparator by default.  `<=` is not required unless you provide a custom comparator.)

Also, always choosing last element as the pivot can make the code vulnerable to reversely sorted sequences.  You can consider taking a random number generator to randomize the choice if this becomes a problem.

Comment: Perhaps add that the comparison operator used by the standard library for user-defined types is always `<`, unless a custom comparator is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

*I usually try to stay away from these aspects of C++, so maybe take what I say with a grain of salt.*

---

From what I can see, your implementation heavily relies on `begin` and `end` being [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/RandomAccessIterator). If I'm not mistaken, your implementation should also work (see notes on complexity below) for [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/BidirectionalIterator) as present e.g. in `std::list`. A minor change should allow the implementation to work with these iterators as well:

- `end - beg > 1` would have to become `std::distance(beg, end) > 1`. `std::distance` has linear complexity for birectional iterators and constant complexity for random access iterators. (See [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)).

and you should be good to go. This is the *simplest* change that I could think of, but I'm pretty sure that there are more efficient solutions for this check.

*Note on complexity: As [@L.F.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/188857/) pointed out in a comment, quicksort is not a suitable algorithm for bidirectional iterators with regards to complexity, though. Nevertheless, not all hope is lost since at least `std::list` has its own method `std::list::sort` which according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) allows you to perform sorting within the \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)\$ complexity class for compares.*

You could also use the following iterator functions to express some of the parts of your code in a different way:

- `auto piv = end; --piv;` could become `auto piv = std::prev(end);` (See [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev))
- `++index_small;` could become `std::advance(index_small, 1);` (See [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance))

These are not strictly necessary though, since bidirectional iterators also support `operator++` and `operator--`.

You can check an example with `std::list` on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/7r2io).

Comment: I understand the suggestion about using `std::distance`, but bidirectional iterators support `operator++` and `operator--`, right? What is the point of using `std::prev` and `std::advance`?

Comment: using `std::distance` to check if the range has more than 1 element seems inefficient for bidirectional iterators. Perhaps an "increase check if end, increase check if end" approach would be better for bidirectional iterators, but I imagine that'd affect efficiency detrimentally for random-access iterators.

Comment: The main reason why I assumed `begin` and `end` were random access iterators is that `std::sort` assumes the same.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the reason why the standard dictates to only accept random access iterators in `std::sort` when looking at the draft. My best guess would be that it allows to use more sorting algorithms in the actual implementation, e.g. Wikipedia seems to hint towards a [hybrid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(C%2B%2B)#Complexity_and_implementations) in the GCC.implementation.

Comment: I am afraid I have to disagree.  Quick sort isn’t suitable for non random access iterators.  The time complexity will go beyond quadratic.

Comment: @L.F.: (Forgive me my bitterness) I forgot that we are in C++ here, where you cannot do something for the sake of doing it, because it might not be optimal ;-) I included your feedback on the complexity issue in the post.